# How to multiply a list by another list?

Tags: python

## This is the programing i used:

```
    import math
iq= (input("enter the price")).split()
fp=(input ("enter the price")).split()
for i in range(len(iq)):
    for n in range(len(fp)):
        print (int(iq[i])* int(fp[i]))
```

## I want it to print:

*multiply each 'iq' by the corresponding 'fp'*

```
1
4
6
```

## It prints:

*multiply each 'iq' by each 'fp'*

```
1
2
3
2
4
6
3
6
9
```

Comment: What purpose do you think your second to last line serves (`for n in …`)? That is essentially the cause of your problems.

Comment: Yep, you only have to loop through one of the lists (if both are the same length) and then print the multiplication using the index (which corresponds for both lists).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, both lists should have the same length right? If so, you can just use one for loop:

```
for i in range(len(iq)):    
    print (int(iq[i])* int(fp[i]))
```

Also, should the input be appended to a list instead of set equal to a variable?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that mistake.